# Rule of English phonology that prevents /j/ and /w/ from occurring in the ends of syllables

Tags: phonology, phonotactics

I'm quite sure I've seen a rule in English phonology that says that /j/ (the "y" sound) and /w/ (the "w" sound) should not occur in the ends of English syllables, but I haven't had much luck finding that rule anywhere on the web.

The rules I'm talking about are called **"Phonotactics rules"**. As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics), "Phonotactics is a branch of phonology that deals with restrictions in a language on the permissible combinations of phonemes. Phonotactics defines permissible syllable structure, consonant clusters and vowel sequences by means of phonotactic constraints."

An example of the rules is that /ŋ/ (the "ng" sound) cannot begin a syllable, but can end one.

I search through different websites in hopes of finding the rule that restricts /w/ and /j/ at the end of syllables, but of no use. Does this "Phonotactic rule" exist in English phonology? Can anyone provide a source that confirms this?

Comment: /y/ and /w/ are semivowels, and not part of diphthongs. But English tense vowels are all automatically diphthongized when stressed, so that _stay_ is phonemically /ste/ in American English, but phonetically [stej]. Hence the rule for semivowels that you recall is redundant because in the phonemic system you're describing, phonemic semivowels are intended not to be used as offglides. No doubt there are other notations to take care of that. It's important to note that there is no single standard phonemic or phonetic system for English. Too much variation, too many linguists.

Comment: I'd love to see any such list of rules in one place.

Comment: So cow, now brow, boy, toy are not examples of these sounds at the ends of words?

Comment: Sorry, you mean j at the end of a word as in Taj?

Comment: @Xanne: /j/ is the 'y' as in ***y**es*, not the J in 'Taj'.

Comment: But hay, may, say, today don’t count?

Comment: ost common use maybe “you” in “Ya wanna go tuh lunch?” Yah, sure.

Comment: @Xanne /j/ is IPA symbol for the Y sound (I know it's kind of misleading, but that's what it is). The "w" at the end of *cow, now, brow* etc is "letter", not "sound"; the sound at the end of those words is a vowel **ʊ** (cow = kaʊ), but it has a close relationship with /w/ which I'm not going to discuss. ..... . The Y in "you", and the like is at the start of a syllable, not the end. (I know my question is kind of confusing.... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list in the Wikipedia article you mentioned does mention "No glides in syllable codas (excluding the offglides of diphthongs)", cited to Harley (2003).